# How to continue a loop on a new line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and have a problem that asks to output "@"a certain number of times based upon the value that the user entered. However it also asks to do it twice on two different lines.

I understand that I need to utilize a loop to output the "@" character.

```
num = int(input())
counter = 0
while counter != num:
    print("@", end='')
    counter = counter + 1
```

In the case of num = 3, the output I receive is `@@@` however, it is supposed to be

```
@@@  
@@@
```

Comment: Remove the `end=''`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bit of a trick question. You are on the right path requiring a loop but you need to loop the required number of times eg

```py
NUMBER_OF_LINES = 2

num = int(input())

# Loop the required number of lines
for _ in range(NUMBER_OF_LINES):
    # Print the number of "@" symbols. Multiplying a string duplicates it.
    print("@" * num)
```

That will produce the required results.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize you could duplicate a string by multiplying it

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
num = int(input())
num_of_lines = 2
for i in range(num_of_lines):
    counter = 0
    while counter != num:
        print("@", end='')
        counter = counter + 1
    print()
```

Comment: The inner counter can be replaced with `print("@" * num)`

Comment: @langstonw, you can upvote answers if any of them was useful for you :)